# How to save captured image inside folder using codeigniter (image captured by javascript code)?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Hi everyone I had written code to capture image of div tag when click on button and javascript code will capture that image ,but i want to save that captured image using codeigniter but we can't using default codeigniter upload method because upload only work for input type file which create one object but here getting captured image by javascript so i want to upload that image in folder so please tell me how to do that using codeigniter.below  i mentioned my code.

```
Html code....
<div id="target" style="border: 1px solid #CCC;padding: 5px;margin: 5px;">
    <div>
        <p>PHP is a server-side scripting language designed primarily for web development.</p>
    </div>
</div>
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
        <input type="hidden" name="img_value" id="img_value" value="" />
    </form>
<input type="submit" value="Screenshot" onclick="capture();" />
```

javascript code to captured image and call ajax to save image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function capture() {
            $('#target').html2canvas({
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    //Set hidden field's value to image data
                    $('#img_value').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                    //Submit the form1
                    var hid_img=$("#img_value").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?= base_url('controller/save_img') ?>",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            hid_img: hid_img,
                        },
                        success: function (response) {

                            $(".show_img").html(response);

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

code in controller method of codeigniter to save image in folder...

```
public function save_img() {

$data = $this->input->post($hid_img);
    $file = md5(uniqid()) . '.png';

    // remove "data:image/png;base64,"
    $uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);

    // save to file in uploads folder of codeigniter
    file_put_contents('./uploads'.$file, base64_decode($uri));

}
to store image in table
$res=$this->db->insert('demo',array('img'=>base_url('uploads/').$file));
    $detail = $this->db->select('*')->from('demo')->where('id', $this->db->insert_id())->get()->row();
    echo '<img src="'.base_url('uploads/').$detail->message.'" style="width:500px;"/>';
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution? also `$this->input->post($hid_img)` should be `$this->input->post('hid_img')`

Comment: @Alex this code is not saving file to folder

Comment: well if this is your actual code you should be getting an error for the thing i mentioned in my first comment. do some debugging and come back with the error. things dont fail without a reason.

Comment: @Alex  showing error you did not select file to upload

Comment: do not use the person who answered code. it is not applicable to your situation as you even noticed in your question. the ci upload library only handles file uploads, not base64 post streams. essentially it only works when you have a *file* input. anyways, use your code, and fix the error i mentioned above and do some debugging.

Comment: oh also `./uploads` should probably have an end slash: `'./uploads/'.$file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly elucidated the upload library only works with **file** inputs and not base64 streams. So you can't use that.

Using your method, you have a few errors in your code that need to be addressed:

1. `$this->input->post($hid_img)` should be `$this->input->post('hid_img')`
2. `./uploads` should probably have an end slash: `'./uploads/'.$file`

Comment: which code should i use file_put_content or codeigniter upload method

Comment: if you read my previous comment it should be clear. but *your method* e.g. file put contents

Comment: i need your more help please while updating path in table  i am getting error  my code inserting path  i have mentioned in my updated question please suggest me solution.

Comment: you should really start a new question instead of editing an already answered one. important info is missing. anyways im off to bed. when you create a new question ill take a look tm, but by that time someone probably will have answered you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample. It is working good. First, if you check upload library.

```
 $config = array(
        'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
        'max_height' => "768",
        'max_width' => "1024"
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('taskcat_img'))  
        {  
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();  
        }  
        else  
        {                   
            $data = $this->upload->data();  
            $imgval = array('success' => 'success' ,'data_image' => $data["file_name"]);  
            echo json_encode($imgval );
}
```

Comment: but here  i am not getting input type file so how can i take $this->upload->do_upload('taskcat_img');

Comment: after doing all of steps you mentioned it is showing error 'you did not select file to upload'

Comment: $this->upload->do_upload('taskcat_img');  you using your file name (taskcat_img)

Comment: I have used my file name $this->upload->do_upload($hid_img''); but still not uploading image

Comment: do not use $ symbol.( $hid_img).
use this
$this->upload->do_upload("hid_img'');